# Docusign First API Call

Tags: docusignapi

```php
$email = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$integratorKey = "INTE-0f494cd8-d0c4-4cd1-9f46-85a86435d749";
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$curl_error=curl_error($curl);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 200 ) {
echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
exit(-1);
}
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);
//--- display results
echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";
```

This is what DocuSign says to do, to retrieve the Account ID and Base URL. But in my case it always says:

> error calling webservice, status is:0

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying it in my local xampp server.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or some security software that might be intercepting your request?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CA doesn't contain the correct update for the DocuSign Certficiate.

Could you add this to your code just to see if it's working, if it is then you'll have to fix the CA (I don't recommend leaving this, because it disables the Cert check).

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Wilson. It was really helpful.I've been able to apply the docusign API in my website with something left.Can you help me out in this regard.I've a developer account where I get the integrator key from. I've been able to redirect the user back after signing. But important things i need to get done:  1. At top of every page in my signing document says "Demonstration Document Only". How can I get rid of this?  2. I want both user and admin to get signing pdf file in their email. But now recipient is not receiving any email.Just two email is sent to the email address used for dev account.